# Representing state of duplicate records across databases

Tags: duplication

I'm needing help formalizing this problem so that I can better get a handle on it. Or so I can at least better do google searches for it.

Suppose an external system and your system maintain the same kind of data, but the data models in each are different from each other. However, some external agency has designated a spec that requires that communication include some subset (or if your data is incomplete, subsets of that subset) of the data. If the record represents a set of template diagrams for your team, one could imagine, the creation date, the file owner, and number of diagrams of each type could be suitable criteria. If the record represents a person, one could imagine that name, sex, date of birth, address are potentially suitable criteria. So the spec would say, all communications will follow some schema that include only those data I described as suitable criteria.

If a record is in both systems, then if both have all the criteria information then we could use a element-wise equality to match, and maybe if they don't have all the data, there could be some fuzzy match score when each criteria is compared. But the fuzzy match could get tricky if data for the shared concept for the record is changed in only one of the databases. Maybe it would be best if there were communications to describe updates to data.

Now, data duplication could happen within either system, and attempting a fuzzy match on an incoming query could be non unique if the criteria data isn't a full set.

What are some ways to model the states of the concept that each record is representing so that I can better understand how duplicates in either system, or updates/erroneous values in either system?

I've thought maybe a state diagram may help, view by pasting this code into [mermaid viewer live](https://mermaid.live)

But it quickly gets out of hand with the coupling of states for each system. And having 3 data bases becomes quickly intractable. **I'm hoping for some tool, diagram, or anything else to help me think about this product space of state diagrams.**

```
stateDiagram-v2
[Synchronous] --> [Fuzzy_Match]: edit/remove any match criteria in one system
[Fuzzy_Match] --> [Synchronous]: edit data such that all match across systems
[Synchronous] --> [1_duplicate_in_one_system]: create duplicate in one system
[1_duplicate_in_one_system] --> [Synchronous]: remove duplicate, resolving merges
[>1_duplicates_in_one_system] --> [>1_duplicates_in_one_system]: add another duplicate
[1_duplicate_in_one_system] --> [>1_duplicates_in_one_system]: add another duplicate
[>1_duplicates_in_one_system] --> [1_duplicate_in_one_system]: remove one duplicate, resolving merges
[1_duplicate_in_one_system] --> [1_duplicate_in_each_system]: create duplicate in system that doesn't yet have duplicate
[1_duplicate_in_each_system] --> [>1_and_1_for_each_system]: create another duplicate in either system
[1_duplicate_in_each_system] --> [1_duplicate_in_one_system]: remove duplicate from either system
```

Comment: This does look like convoluted description of ETL. The new specification describes communication between whom? Between your two databases or between your databases and the agency that invented that specification?

Comment: The spec would describe communication between databases. But the ETL wiki led me to the deduplication wiki which has a model that doesn't look like it extends cleanly to more databases. Is there perhaps a reason to not think of >2 systems in this way?

Comment: Yes, ETL usually happens between two databases. If you need to more databases, then you would have do multiple ETL sessions. In this case, the usual solution is to designate one DB (or several DBs) as a "central" warehouse and synch all databases with it.